# Downloads vs Update charts in new iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Where can I see the new downloads vs update charts? In my case I see only a single line with units per day.

Some hints and maybe screenshots will be useful!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this has been removed from the new iTunes Connect Sales & Downloads.

> Units is the aggregated number of items sold, refunded, or updated for a given day or week.

However, the data is still in the raw reports:

> Update transactions have the Product Type Identifier 7.

<sup>Source: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/5.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.4.1</sup>